# Change excerpt length from letters to words - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

This code seems to only affect letters in stead of words. How can I change it to count words in my excerpt instead of letters? I would also like to add "..." at the end of my excerpt.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'reigel_woocommerce_short_description', 0, 15);
function reigel_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
        $post_excerpt = substr($post_excerpt, 0, 200);
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Use [wp_trim_words()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) or [wp_trim_excerpt()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) instead.

Comment: I'm not so sure how I could implement this with the code above.

Comment: Place  either of those two functions instead of `substr()`, and that's it. I'd use `wp_trim_words()` as it: 'trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text'.